# Blank order detail page after rename product SKU in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, sku, order-details

When I rename product's SKU which product customer has ordered. After that when I go to order detail page that is showing only information tab only nothing else 
[image]

These are the security patches installed

PATCH_SUPEE-3941_EE_1.14.0.1_v1-2015-02-10-08-32-02.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-5994_CE_1.6.0.0_v1-2015-05-15-04-34-46.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-07-07-09-06-30.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-6482_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-08-03-06-51-10.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-59-27.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-29-05.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2016-01-20-04-47-00.sh

PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.8.1.0_v2-2016-10-14-09-35-11.sh

Please help guys I am stuck.

Comment: Hi. Did you check you logs? Your reason will be revealed in either the webserver error log, or in the exception.log in magento var/log/ folder. Not really much that can be done to help with some kind of error to work from.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @ProxiBlue but there is nothing in error logs :(